# Tkinter, Trying to generate Checkbutton in loop

Tags: python, variables, loops, button, tkinter

I am trying to generate standalone Checkbuttons in loop but who has the same name Checkbutton works together. I don't know where is my mistake...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import os
from Tkinter import * 
import ttk 

def checkBoxText(st):
    if st == 0:
        st="Disabled"
    if st == 1:
        st="Enabled"
    return st

root = Tk()

winSt={1:1,2:1,3:0,4:0}
cbTexts={}
cbVariables={}
cb={}
cb_x={ "1":"0.0", "2":"0.0", "3":"0.6", "4":"0.6" }
cb_y={"1": "0.1", "2": "0.8", "3": "0.1", "4": "0.8"}
for i in sorted(winSt.keys()):
    cbTexts[i] = StringVar()
    cbTexts[i].set(checkBoxText(winSt[i]))
    cbVariables[i] = IntVar()
    cbVariables[i].set(winSt[i])

    cb[i] = Checkbutton(root, text=cbTexts[i].get(), variable=cbVariables[i].get())
    cb[i].place(relx=cb_x[str(i)], rely=cb_y[str(i)], relheight=0.1,relwidth=0.4)
mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't know where your mistake is either. It would help if you explained your expected output vs. your actual output and any errors you may be getting.

Comment: Sorry i correct the title and question because i did wrote combo box instead of check button.
So i tink i see the mistake, when i create the checkbuttons in loop and set the "variable" configuration and who has the same variable value they works like just one checkbutton.

Maybe i have to check the checkbuttons after loop but how?
cb["1"].configure(variable=1) this is not working.

Comment: Change `variable=cbVariables[i].get()` to `variable=cbVariables[i]`.

Comment: Oh my GOD. realy thank you very much @Joel Cornett.
it made me crazy until now. it works:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
cb[i] = Checkbutton(..., variable=cbVariables[i].get())
```

When you use the `variable` attribute, you must give it a reference to a variable object, not the value contained in the object. Change the code to this:

```
cb[i] = Checkbutton(..., variable=cbVariables[i])
```

You're making a somewhat similar mistake with the checkbutton text. You are creating a StringVar, but then using the value of the StringVar for the checkbutton text instead of the actual variable. Syntactically that's correct when used with the `text` attribute, but it's doing more work than it needs to. You should either use the `textvariable` attribute, or simply *not* create a StringVar.

Here's how to use the `textvariable` attribute instead of the `text` attribute:

```
cb[i] = Checkbutton(root, textvariable=cbTexts[i], ...)
```

You don't need the StringVar at all if this text will never change. If that's the case, you can just do this and save a couple lines of code:

```
cb[i] = Checkbutton(root, text=checkBoxText(winSt[i]), ...)
```